# Typescript/Angular: static class reference as function parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, function, generics, parameters

I'm quite new to typescript, and found that mapping an http response to a class was really nifty, like

```
getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
  return this.http.get<Movie[]>(this.endpoint);
}
```

returning a populated array of `Movie` classes (just an example)

That made me attempt to generalize this somewhat, by calling on a hypothetical `get` method in a parent class, like

```
// child
getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
  return this.super.get(class_reference_here, this.endpoint);
}

// parent
get(reference: any, endpoint: string): Observable<any> /* or <any[]> ?? */  {
    return this.http.get<reference[]>(endpoint);
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this? Is there a way to populate `class_reference_here` with something sensible? Does it spit in the face of Typescript? I don't know! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could always create a class instance & use it!

Comment: can you use generics, something like `get<T>(reference: T, endpoint: string): Observable<T[]>`? though not sure what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

```
// child
getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
  return this.super.get<Movie[]>(this.endpoint);
}

// parent
get<T>(endpoint: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(endpoint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the point of adding an abstraction layer to httpClient or whatever you are trying to do. Nevertheless you should have a look at [Generics in Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg;
}
```